# how do I create an image that is an anchor using itext

Tags: java, itext

I basically want a clickable logo in my pdf.
How do I create an Anchor using an Image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Image` in a `Chunk`, and call `chunk.setAnchor()`.